# How do I split a field in tab separated values?

Tags: regex

I'm trying to automate a series of regular expressions that I perform regularly by using Sublime Text 3 and RegReplace. After running a few rules, I get data that looks like this (hundreds of lines, tab-separated)

```
M   543 E0385-C-R   BSC SDA SV  After   Quarterly   N/A N/A
M   543 A-2 Room    SDA AV  N/A Quarterly   N/A N/A
M   543 H9  BSC SDA SV  After   Quarterly   N/A N/A
```

My next step is to split the third columns at the first dash '-' if it exists by replacing the '-' with a \t. If there is no dash, I would like to add a \t at the end of the column (this is to keep my columns consistent across all the rows. Here is the output I'm looking for:

```
M   543 E0385   C-R BSC SDA SV  After   Quarterly   N/A N/A
M   543 A   2   Room    SDA AV  N/A Quarterly   N/A N/A
M   543 H9      BSC SDA SV  After   Quarterly   N/A N/A
```

The first two lines split at the first dash. The third line does not have a dash, so I insert a tab at the end of the third field.

So far I have figured out how to match the content of the columns (It still seems a little clumsy) with:

```
(?<=\t|^)[a-zA-Z0-9-\/]*(?=\t|$)
```

I would then find the third match and further process it with to replace the first dash. Not really sure how to do this (would be happy to have someone show me how you do this 'nested' evaluation).

A different approach brought me here:

```
(?<=\t\d{3}\t)([a-zA-Z0-9-]*)\K-
```

This assumes that there are always three digits in the second column... an assumption I don't trust.

So a generalization of the pattern got me:

```
(?:\S+\t){2}\S*?\K(-)
```

which is pretty good, I think. See it [here](https://regex101.com/r/mMoFpb/2).

- How do I get this expression to match the end of the 'word' if there is no dash?
- Can I make it more robust (so a dash in a subsequent column does not match)?
- Is there a better approach to this problem (like the two-level match above, maybe) and how do I implement it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is indeed not a good idea to rely on the presence of 3 digits as an indication for the second column.

Instead make use of the start-of-line assertion (`^`) and match the first two columns and the third column up to the first hyphen (if it is there). Then start capturing from that point onwards (`\K`) and capture the hyphen if it is there, otherwise you'll just capture an empty string. The replace that with a TAB:

Find: `^((?:[^\t]*\t){2}[^\t-]*)\K-?`

Replace: `\t`

Comment: This works just as expected. Brilliant. I like your use of tab, not-tab to navigate the columns. Now that its right there I can see how it works, but I would not have come up with this on my own any time soon. Thank you!

Comment: How should I edit or rename this post to make it useful for others?